# Flutter app: Chewie throws "Failed to load video: Cannot Open" if I load a thumbnail from firebase storage before the video

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I ran into a problem trying to make an app, so I isolated the problem in the basic app shown below. It has an `Inkwell` widget that initially displays a thumbnail; tapping it will switch the thumbnail to a video. (The `FirebaseAPI.getNailURL` and `FirebaseAPI.getVideoURL` methods, as well as the `ChewieBox` widget, are my own custom methods and widgets, which I show below as well. I doubt that the implementation for `ChewieBox` is important though. It's just a container for a `Chewie` video player.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import '../api/firebase_api.dart';
import '../general/chewie_box.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'video_player test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late Widget imageOrVideo;

  final postData = {
    'user': 'nathan',
    'videoName': 'nathan2021-12-16T13:25:35.758371'
  };

  Widget thumbnail() {
    final thumbnailURL = FirebaseAPI.getNailURL(postData['videoName']);
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: thumbnailURL,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Image.network(snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }

  Widget thumbnail_not_firebase() {
    return Image.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg');
  }

  Widget video() {
    final videoURL = FirebaseAPI.getVideoURL(postData['videoName']);
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: videoURL,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ChewieBox(
                VideoPlayerController.network(snapshot.data!), false);
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }

  void swap() {
    setState(() {
      imageOrVideo = video();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageOrVideo = thumbnail_not_firebase();
    // imageOrVideo = thumbnail();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: swap,
        child: imageOrVideo,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`FirebaseAPI` methods:

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class FirebaseAPI {
  static getVideoURL(videoName) {
    return FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('videos/$videoName').getDownloadURL();
  }

  static getNailURL(videoName) {
    return FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('thumbnails/$videoName')
        .getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

`ChewieBox` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

class ChewieBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  final bool looping;
  final dynamic aspectRatio;

  const ChewieBox(
    this.videoPlayerController,
    this.looping, {
    this.aspectRatio,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChewieBoxState createState() => _ChewieBoxState();
}

class _ChewieBoxState extends State<ChewieBox> {
  late ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: widget.looping,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chewie(controller: _chewieController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }
}
```

The problem is that if the thumbnail is taken from some random image from the internet, the video works; however, if the thumbnail is an image taken from my own `firebase` storage, the video (I tested with videos from the same `firebase` storage, random videos online, and also local "asset" videos) will not play, but throw the following error:

[image]

There is also another error message in the console which appears after I close the app:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)
```

I am simply baffled by how the loading of the thumbnail from my `firebase` storage can break the loading of the video afterwards, while using a random image from the internet has no issues. The error message isn't very helpful either. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example video url from your firebase storage please?

Comment: @FurkanKURT the video that is played doesn’t matter, it throws error whether it’s asset or network or file

Comment: I have same call stack on chewie like yours. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that content-type header is correct.
You can see how to do this here : [SettableMetadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage_platform_interface/latest/firebase_storage_platform_interface/SettableMetadata-class.html).

Also, you can check file content-type in Firebase storage user interface.